# Totality in Hilbert space used to show an inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $e_k\in L_2(a,b), k=1,2,3,...$ be an orthonormal sequence in $L_2(a,b)$. I want to show if it is total then the following holds for all $x\in (a,b)$:
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\int_a^xe_k(t)dt|^2=x-a$.
Here's what I've done:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\int_a^xe_k(t)dt|^2=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\int_a^be_k(t)dt|^2-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\int_b^xe_k(t)dt|^2$
I think that I have use the fact that I'm in a Hilbert space and $<x,y>=\int_a^bx(t)y(t)dt$ and the Parseval's identity since we have totality: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|<x,e_k>|^2=\|x\|^2$. I just don't know how to use ir because of all the integral's b,a,x changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: fix $x \in (a,b)$ and set $f(t) = 1_{(a,x)}(t)$.  Then the left side of your equation is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\langle f, e_k \rangle|^2$ which by Parseval equals $\|f\|^2$.  But you can compute $\|f\|^2$ directly...